# Retrieving current text inside editable span tag

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, summernote

I am using Summernote (http://summernote.org/) to create an editor where users can edit a message they have created. Inside the text shown in the editor when the page loads, I have a few `<span>` tags that wrap some sections of the message, and each of these has a different id (for example, `<span id="something">`).

When the user presses the save button, I want to retrieve the text inside each `<span>` tag at that moment. I tried using something like `$("#something").text()`, but that only retrieves the text that was inside the spans when the page was loaded, not the current text. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summernote, create another span, if you use id you get the text of the element with display:'none', try to use class and get the last element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#summernote').summernote();
  console.log($('.test:last').text());
  $('.save').on('click', function() {
    console.log($('.test:last').text());
    return false;
  });
});
```

[See the Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/psvReD03FsrVUbxtvHK4?p=preview)

Comment: You sir are the best! Thanks a lot!